# How do I exclude PDF file from a Google site search?

Tags: google-search, search

I want to display of the indexed file from a particular section of my website.

So I type this into the address bar:

```
https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&q=site:example.com%2Fsubfolder%2F
```

I also want to exclude the PDF files that have been indexed. How do I change the URL I am using so that the results never include PDF files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the [inurl](http://www.googleguide.com/advanced_operators_reference.html#inurl) operator for Google should do the trick.   Assuming your PDF files all have the `.pdf` extension, adding `-inurl:pdf` to your search will exclude those URLs.

```
https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&q=site:example.com%2Fsubfolder%2F+-inurl%3Apdf
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could use the `filetype` operator instead of `inurl`, eg. `-filetype:pdf`